# SharePoint deleting html attribute

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, css, html, classic-experience

I want to put a multilevel accordion based on this : https://codepen.io/gamechci669/pen/VwEKpbb

When I edit the HTML code on my page, lines with attributes "for" lose this!

For example:

```
<input class="ac-input" id="ac-3.1" type="checkbox"/>
<label class="ac-label" for="ac-3.1">
```

Becomes:

```
<input class="ac-input" id="ac-3.1" type="checkbox"/> <label class="ac-label">
```

Why does it happen ? Is there a way to make this work ?

Because when I use the development tools in the browser and add the attribute manually, it works.

PS: I am using SharePoint 2016 on-premises classic pages.